# Apache fastcgi catalyst Bugzilla REST api @INC issue

Tags: perl, bugzilla, catalyst

I am trying to set up [Bugzilla REST api (bzapi)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla%3aREST_API) but I've hit a roadblock. I'm setting it up as a FastCGI prosess in a virtualhost in apache. I can execute the script from `/var/www/bzapi` by executing `./script/bugzilla_api_fastcgi.pl`, but not from `/var/www/bzapi/script` using `./bugzilla_api_fastcgi.pl` as a I get the same error as in apache.

**The apache error:**

```
[Tue Mar 06 15:04:49 2012] [warn] FastCGI: server "/var/www/bzapi/script/bugzilla_api_fastcgi.pl" started (pid 13329)
Can't locate Bugzilla/API.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 50
[Tue Mar 06 15:04:50 2012] [warn] FastCGI: server "/var/www/bzapi/script/bugzilla_api_fastcgi.pl" (pid 13329) terminated by calling exit with status '2'
```

**The apache config:**

```
FastCgiServer /var/www/bzapi/script/bugzilla_api_fastcgi.pl -processes 10 -idle-timeout 180
Alias /bzapi /var/www/bzapi/script/bugzilla_api_fastcgi.pl/
```

**The script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Catalyst::ScriptRunner;
Catalyst::ScriptRunner->run('Bugzilla::API', 'FastCGI');

1;
```

What's a clean way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add use lib lines to your script. Locate Api.pm file and add that line to your script. Maybe this works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib '/var/www/bzapi';

use Catalyst::ScriptRunner;
Catalyst::ScriptRunner->run('Bugzilla::API', 'FastCGI');

1;
```

Comment: It's not my script, it's distrubted from mozilla.org so the preferable way is to not modify it.

Comment: I attempted your fix, which did solve the immediate error - but then it didn't read configuration file

Comment: You have to specify it somewhere. Are you tried find_script_class or find_script_traits?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader, "    *

      $ENV{ MYAPP_CONFIG }
    *

      $ENV{ CATALYST_CONFIG }
    *

      $c->config->{ 'Plugin::ConfigLoader' }->{ file }
    *

      $c->path_to( $application_prefix )
"

Comment: You could set an enviroment variable to find out where is the config.yaml is located.

Comment: by the way, Are you tried to run ./checksetup.pl --check-modules? http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/installation.html or http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.16/html/stepbystep.html